# Java - get from Guava RangeMap returns null while key is present in the Range

Tags: java, collections, guava

I tried to implemented a method to search for a string in a RangeMap. I want to check that the metricName is in the RangeMap and that it is present in a given time range.

```
private static RangeMap<Long, String> salesRangeMap = TreeRangeMap.create();
salesRangeMap.put(
      Range.closed(1540038517L, 1540645753L), "Metric1");

public static boolean isMetricPresent(String metricName, long theKey) {
             String metricFromMap = Objects.requireNonNull(salesRangeMap.get(theKey));
    if (StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(metricName, metricFromMap)) {
        return true;
    } 
       return false;  
}
```

The key in a salesRangeMap is a Range From `October 20, 2018 12:28:37 PM` to `October 27, 2018 1:09:13 PM` (in human readable format).

However when I call the `isMetricPresent` method like this and pass it `System.currentTimeMillis()` as the key (which is equal to this timestamp value `1540476195830` -> `October 25, 2018 2:03:15.830 PM`), it returns `null` on this call `salesRangeMap.get(theKey)`.

```
long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); // 1540476195830
boolean isPresent = isMetricPresent("Metric1", currentTime);
```

As for my current understanding, the key `currentTime` is present in the Range of the `salesRangeMap`. What is wrong in my current approach?

Comment: Can you please post a minimal, complete, and verifiable example (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve )?

Comment: @isnot2bad above is exactly the code that I'm testing right now

Comment: Why not use `RangeMap<LocalDateTime, String>` instead? Then you wouldn't have any ambiguities over seconds/milliseconds used in the Long values.

Comment: @samba I doubt this is *exactly* the code you're testing. E.g. second line is a solely statement that is not within any method.

Comment: @isnot2bad No need to downvote if you just _doubt_

Comment: @samba I've not downvoted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it seems to me that `1540645753` < `1540476195830` - you're storing seconds in map, but query millis.